# When I click to the next page on pagination, 404 error run

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

I was trying to do pagination in CodeIgniter but I did something wrong I guess.

- The pagination links are seen on the bottom of the page. (OK)
- When I click the numbers on the pagination links, an error (404) is occurred. (This is the problem I couldn't solve)

My codes are below.

blog_model

```
function posts($cat_id='')
{
    $config['base_url']     = 'http://example.com/blog';
    $config['total_rows']   = 3;
    $config['per_page']     = 1;
    $config['num_links']    = 20;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    if($cat_id) $this->db->where('cat_id',$cat_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    return $query->result();
}
```

blog_view

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Comment: Pagination in CI can get tricky.  Pagination simply constructs the links, you'll still have to properly construct the Limit and Offset yourself.  Focus your efforts on how you've constructed your query instead of on the pagination.

Comment: Okey! I will focus on it. I will look for more information on the internet related to your advice. Maybe that's what I need as a jr. developer.

Comment: I am also not sure your segment 3 is correct for the location of the page number.  If it's `/blog/posts/cat_id/1`, then the page number (your offset) is at segment number 4.

Comment: Thanks man! This advice saved me. The codes I published was totally correct as I see. Because I changed the route on  $config['base_url']     = 'http://example.com/blog/index'; and also I changed the number of segment and it is worked. now the link is seen example.com/blog/index/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination in CI can get tricky. **Pagination simply constructs the links, you'll still have to properly construct the `limit` and `offset` for the database query.**

You must pass the page number into your function from the URL

```
function posts($cat_id='', $page = FALSE)
{
    $config['base_url']     = 'http://example.com/blog';
    $config['total_rows']   = 3;
    $config['per_page']     = 1;
    $config['num_links']    = 20;
    $config['uri_segment']  = 3; // <-  verify this one

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    // set the page to 1 if the page is missing from the URL
    $page   = ($page === FALSE ? 1 : $page); 

    // calculate the offset for the query
    $offset = ($page - 1 ) * $config['per_page'];

    if($cat_id) $this->db->where('cat_id',$cat_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'], $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

---

**EDIT as per comments:**

I am also not sure your segment 3 is correct for the location of the page number. If it's `/blog/posts/cat_id/1`, then the page number (your offset) is at segment number 4.

Comment: Actually the problem was the route. I found out it after your second advice about segment. After I changed base_url with the name of function such as blog/index/ and also I changed the number of segment and It is worked! Really thank you. And I will keep my eyes on your first advice about constructions.

Comment: @Bari, yes, it's difficult to know without seeing your URL's and routes.  I've updated my answer to make it more useful to others.

Comment: After now I will give more details before sending my question. :) It's my bad. Sorry about it.